# What is default PyCharm's code formatter?

Tags: python, pycharm, formatting

I don't use Pycharm as my Python environment, neither do I have it on my PC.
However, we often have dicusses with coworkers about codestyle and while I prefer black, they use internal PyCharm formatter.

I didn't found any mention at JetBrains website, what the thing it is, any suggestions?

Comment: Are you asking what all the default settings are for the PyCharm formatting options?

Comment: @Barmar Not exactly. Like, if I want to bring exactly this formatter (the default Pycharm's one) to VSCode, how can search for it?

Comment: You're assuming that JetBrains is using a third-party formatter rather than their own internal code. I don't think that's the case.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/reformat-and-rearrange-code.html),

> PyCharm adheres to PEP8 rules and requirements for arranging and formatting Python code.

From how I understand it, there is still some flexibility under pep8.

For example, the default formatter on Pycharm allows for use of single or double quotes on strings and does not require that to be consistent in the code.

Whereas, Black is very specific to expect double quotes on strings across *all files* unless configured otherwise.

I presume Pycharm's default IDE python formatter will make the minimum changes necessary to fulfill pep8 and the exact behavior is determined by the individual's coding preferences.